# Terminal Command for Stock Information

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, stock

I would like to have a command that gets me the value a stock closed at.

How can I do this?

Comment: You will need to decide from which source you want to get your data from first, i.e. bloomberg etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty open ended question and not very specific, so I'm basically just thinking out loud here. Tou would have to write a command line program that took in a stock code and then went off to some kind of web service and fetched the appropriate value for that code.

So do you want something that just outputs to the terminal window (ie. "standard out")?
`>stock AAPL`
`339.30`

`stock` would be the name of the compiled binary.
The program takes in a single argument for the stock code. It send that code to a web service that provides pricing information, then parses the result and spites it back out.

Comment: Do you understand the basics of programming? The first thing to do would be to open Xcode and work your way through some beginner tutorials for Objective-C.

Comment: I'm quite proficient in objective-c actually. Please do not condescend because my question seems stupid. Thank you. So, how do I turn this into a command. In other words, I'm trying to create a custom command (not execute a program).

Comment: Fair enough. You can put the binary into /usr/local/bin to be able to call it by name from the command line.